Using I2C to receive and send data simultaneously
I am working with the ESP32S3 boards, and currently working on a IoT project where I link two boards via I2C in a master-slave relationship. The master ESP32 is connected to a sensor and would relay data over to the slave ESP32 which plays an audio file from an SD card through a PCM5102 DAC module. The code is fairly straightforward. However, I am struggling to get the audio playing functionality to work when used in conjunction with the slave mode. Is it because I2C only works one-way at any given time? Or is there some way to get this to work?
The audio library I used can be found at - https://github.com/schreibfaul1/ESP32-audioI2S/. The code used is a combination of standard I2C reading and writing with the audio code that can be found in the readme file with the aforementioned library. I am using the arduino framework in platformio, if that proves to be useful. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance!
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Audio.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "FS.h"

//SPI Pins
#define SD_CS D9
#define SPI_MOSI MOSI
#define SPI_MISO MISO
#define SPI_SCK SCK

// I2S Pins
#define I2S_DOUT SDA
#define I2S_BCLK SCL
#define I2S_LRC D6

Audio audio;

// Function to receive signal - Toggles volume based on data received
void receiveSignal(int numBytes)
{
    while(Wire.available())
    {
        bool c = Wire.read();
        if(c)
        {
            audio.setVolume(21);
        }
        else
        {
            audio.setVolume(0);
        }
    }
    Serial.println();
}


// Setup function - Initialises Serial, SPI, SD and Audio Pins
void setup()
{
    pinMode(SD_CS, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(SD_CS, HIGH);

    SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);

    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(5000);

    SD.begin(SD_CS);

    audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
    audio.setVolume(21);

    audio.connecttoFS(SD, "/audio.wav");
    
    Wire.begin(8);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveSignal);
}

// Loop function - Loops audio
void loop()
{
    audio.loop();
}




Your second ESP32 need to be present in slave mode to get audio data.
The same ESP32 needs to be in master mode to play it.
This is in conflict. Try creating 2 instances of I2C, one for each task. Maybe this is helpful:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-i2c-communication-arduino-ide


OP's ESP32 slave is supposed to receiving data in I2C and sending audio out in I2S. There is no conflict about having I2C in both as a slave and as a master.
